# Aurelia binding causes VS editor to show "Unexpected token" error

Tags: visual-studio, aurelia

I've opened the `app.html` sample from Aurelia in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3.
Although the applications works properly, but the editor shows an error because it doesn't find `value.bind` as a valid html.

[image]

What could I do to remove this annoying error in editor?

Comment: It's hard to use visual studio editor these days. You will be happier using Atom or VSCode

Comment: However, there's a VS Plugin in development that should solve these issues

Comment: I don't have this problem at all. The only thing I can think of is perhaps you haven't wrapped your html in a template tag?